# Powershell won't use parameter value from a variable

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

The following command works perfectly:

```
Set-Mailbox $mailbox -EmailAddresses SMTP:am@foo.com,asmo@bar.org,toke@foobar.net
```

Trying to run the same command with the email addresses in a variable crashes.

```
$SMTPAddresses = "SMTP:am@foo.com,asmo@bar.org,toke@foobar.net” 
Set-Mailbox $mailbox -EmailAddresses $SMTPAddress
```

Error:

```
Set-Mailbox : Cannot convert 'SMTP:am@foo.com,asmo@bar.org,toke@foobar.net' to the type 'Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ProxyAddressCollection' required by parameter 'EmailAddresses'. The address 'SMTP:am@foo.com,asmo@bar.org,toke@foobar.net' is invalid: The address 'am@klestrup.dk,asmo@bdk.dk,toke@bdk.dk' is not a valid SMTP address.
At line:1 char:39
+  Set-Mailbox $mailbox -EmailAddresses $SMTPAddresses
+                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Mailbox], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.SetMailbox
```

The variable is a string btw.

```
 $SMTPAddresses.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                            
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                            
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

Any ideas what is causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is rather self-explanatory. `am@foo.com,asmo@bar.org,toke@foobar.net` is not an e-mail address. Try it like this:

```
$SMTPAddresses = 'SMTP:am@foo.com','SMTP:asmo@bar.org','SMTP:toke@foobar.net'
Set-Mailbox $mailbox -EmailAddresses $SMTPAddresses
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an array of two email address strings:

```
$SMTPAddresses = "SMTP:am@foo.com","asmo@bar.org,toke@foobar.net”
```

This is one string of two email addresses joined with a comma:

```
$SMTPAddresses = "SMTP:am@foo.com,asmo@bar.org,toke@foobar.net”
```

Answer (score 0):

A peculiarity on Office 365 powershell using the xxx-UnifiedGroups command

If you're constructing the command like this:

```
$emails  = @()
$emails += "SMTP:primary.address@domain.com"
$emails += "smtp:email2@domain.com"

# I'm splatting here but you can use whatever approach you prefer
$params  = @{}
$params += @{"EmailAddresses" = $emails}
```

And you're getting this error, try making sure you include a tenant address like so:

```
$emails  = @()
$emails += "SMTP:primary.address@domain.com"
$emails += "smtp:email2@domain.com"
$emails += "smtp:email@YourTenant.onmicrosoft.com"

$params  = @{}
$params += @{"EmailAddresses" = $emails}
```

Note: Originally I got past the error using escaping, but that was a red herring.  After getting full end to end working example it turns out you need a "MOERA" address (one that matches your 365 tenant) but the command gives a false error message about not being able to convert to the type 'Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ProxyAddressCollection'.